# AJAX not working on localhost?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xampp

I'm trying to get an AJAX example working but i'm unable to get it working. im using xampp. The code just doesnt seem to work... There is no directory problem btw, i made sure... i checked everything...

rates.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
          return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 & amp; & amp; xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body id="top">
    <br />
    <div class="wrapper col3" style="background-image: url(); opacity: 0.7;">
      <?php include( "header.inc"); ?>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="wrapper col2">
      <?php include( "menu.inc"); ?>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="wrapper col5">
       <h1>Rates</h1>

      <p>Please select an activity to view its rate at Casela. Rates available for both residents and non-residents.</p>
      <form>
        <select name="activity" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
          <option value="">Please select an actvity</option>
          <option value="1">Big Cats (Lions)</option>
          <option value="2">Big Cats (Tigers)</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <div id="txtHint" style="padding: 20px;"></div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
  </body>

</html>
```

getuser.php

```
<?php
$q = $_GET["q"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("rates", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM activities WHERE id = '" . $q . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Activity</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
    <th>Restriction</th>
    <th>Resident</th>
    <th>Non-Resident</th>
    </tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Activity'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Decription'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Duration'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Restriction'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Resident'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['NonResident'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is it doing instead?

Comment: the ajax is not working.. a table should have been generated...but nothing happens...

Comment: i cant figure it out....i checked it several times. is there a problem with the coding?

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 &amp;&amp; xmlhttp.status==200)
```

Should be like:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```